# Jquery not working when using .jsp extension

Tags: jquery, html, jsp

We're trying to change the HTML code to JSP, except that the jQuery is having trouble working.

While it's working fine in HTML, on clicking the `+`(changes to `x`), but when clicking it again, nothing happens. I hope I was able to explain this right, any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```js
$(".plusNav").click(function() {
  var value = $(".plusNav").text();
  if (value === "×") {
    $(".plusNav").html("&#43;");
    $(".plusNav-content a").css("display", "none");
    $(".plusNav-content").css("width", "0");
  } else {
    $(".plusNav").html("&#215;");
    $(".plusNav-content a").css("display", "block");
    $(".plusNav-content").css("width", "75%");
  }
});
```

```css
.plusNav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999999;
  right: 1%;
  top: -2%;
  font-size: 8rem;
  color: #20ed86;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.plusNav-content {
  z-index: 999;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 10%;
  top: 2%;
  right: 2.5%;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
}

.plusNav-content a {
  color: white;
  display: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="plusNav"><span>&#43;</span></div>
<div class="plusNav-content">
  <a href="mailto:info@woodflake.com">info@woodflake.com</a> &nbsp; | &nbsp; <a href="tel:+(91)99261-96966">+(91)99261-96966</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that your code was missing a `})` which I added, as you state it works in HTML so that must just be missing from the question. The file extension makes no difference to JS, so long as the output is HTML. There's not enough information here to help as what you've shown works. Check the console for errors.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Hi, thanks for the reply, I checked the console, but wasn't getting any errors, when the click on the plus, it changes to 'x', but on clicking it again, nothing happens

Comment: In that case it's likely that the `if (value === "×")` condition is not working as you expect. Check what `value` contains

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yeah, turns out the if-else condition isn't working at all the second time I click, but since I clicked it again, it should run again, shouldn't it?

Comment: Depends entirely what the value of `value` is. I'd suggest adding `console.log(value)` first and checking the output

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Its logging `×` when using console.log, it's not even entering the if block, even though I've put the same value in the condition